# Vertex AI Create Tuned Model Internal Error With No Context

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I am using the "Create a tuned model" feature in Google Vertex AI dashboard.

I've been able to upload my jsonl file, but when the tuning job runs, it just fails with no indication of what the error is:

[image: google error]

I can't find any logs or anything that give me any more information.

I've tried running the same via CLI, but having authentication issues there, so feeling stuck.

I've tried using a simplified mock jsonl file to be sure it's not my formatting that is breaking it. Here's my training file:

```
{ "input_text": "input1", "output_text": "output1" }
{ "input_text": "input2", "output_text": "output2" }
{ "input_text": "input3", "output_text": "output3" }
{ "input_text": "input4", "output_text": "output4" }
{ "input_text": "input5", "output_text": "output5" }
{ "input_text": "input6", "output_text": "output6" }
{ "input_text": "input7", "output_text": "output7" }
{ "input_text": "input8", "output_text": "output8" }
{ "input_text": "input9", "output_text": "output9" }
{ "input_text": "input10", "output_text": "output10" }
```

Is there something wrong with my file, or is there any known way to dig deeper into the error?

Any guidance or suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to contact Google Support for this inquiry as they have better visibility on your logs and resources within your project to investigate. cloud.google.com/contact

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the specific problem was that I did not have the 'Cloud Storage Admin' permission set on the account I was running the job with.

Once I added this, it worked. I hit another error next, but that's unrelated.